# HTML table row near the page break doesn't have bottom and top borders

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am banging my head around an issue with some html in it. We are generating a huge table and some of these cells have multiple lines of text. Now when we are printing it, the cells near the page breaks don't seem to retain borders. For example, in the screenshot below, the cell near the bottom of the page doesn't have a border-bottom because it is overflowing to the next page. Similarly, that cell on the next page doesn't have the top-border. Although it is the same cell, is there a way we can have these borders near the page breaks? Also, the number of rows and text in it are dynamic so can't just fix the borders.

```css
@page {
  size: A4;
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}

html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  font-size: 13px;
  position: relative;
  max-width: 1024px;
  margin: auto;
  font-family: 'Noto Sans JP', sans-serif;
}

@media print {
  body {
    font-family: 'Noto Sans JP', sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
}

.exportProfileContent {
  font-family: 'Noto Sans JP', sans-serif;
  width: 100%;
}

.row::before,
.row::after {
  display: table;
  content: " ";
  clear: both;
}

.col {
  width: 100%;
}

.col-2 {
  width: 50%;
}

.col-3 {
  width: 33%;
}

.col-4 {
  width: 25%;
}

.column {
  float: left;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

.t-right {
  text-align: right;
}

.t-center {
  text-align: center;
}

.title {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #000000;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.title-sm {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #a1a1a1;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.label {
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding-right: 15px !important;
}

.pb-10 {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.pb-20 {
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

ol {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

table {
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  /* border-collapse: collapse; */
  border-spacing: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: left;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

table thead th {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 500;
  height: 35px;
  padding: 5px 8px;
  background-color: #E7E7E7;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

table tbody td {
  line-height: 150%;
  font-size: 13px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  min-height: 100%;
  border: 0;
}

.tab_container>tbody>tr>td {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  padding: 6px 10px;
}

.tab_container>tbody>tr>td:nth-child(1) {
  width: 5%;
  text-align: center;
}

.tab_container>tbody>tr>td:nth-child(2) {
  width: 22%;
}

.tab_container>tbody>tr>td:nth-child(3) {
  width: 80%;
}


/*
.tab_container .tab_container>tbody,
.tab_container>tbody>tr,
.tab_container>tbody>tr>td {
    page-break-after: avoid;
    page-break-inside: avoid;
    page-break-before: avoid;
}
*/

.OutlineElement {
  margin: 14px 0 !important;
}

.schemaField {
  display: block;
}

.header_banner {
  width: 100%;
}

.tahomaFont {
  font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Segoe, sans-serif;
}

.footer_banner {
  width: 100%;
}

.pageBreak {
  page-break-after: always;
}


/* .pageBr-B {
  page-break-before: always;
} */


/* .pageBr-I {
  page-break-inside: avoid;
} */

.dNone {
  display: none !important;
}

.img_container {
  width: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.img_container--1 {
  margin: 0 0 0 auto;
}

.img_container--2 {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.img_container img {
  width: 103%;
  margin: -6px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <title>New Generic view</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Noto+Sans+JP:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="exportProfileContent">
    <div class="row employment">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-2 column">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="col-2 column t-right">
          <div>
            <div class="fieldContainer text ">
              <div class="description"><br>
                <div align="right">2021年10月14日</div>
              </div>
              <div class="value"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col column">
          <span class="value">
                        <div class="fieldContainer text ">
                            <div class="description">
                                <div>ABCDEF<br></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="value"></div>
                        </div>ABCDEF
                    </span>
        </div>
        <div class="col column t-right">
        </div>
        <div class="col column t-center pb-10 title">
          <div class="fieldContainer text ">
            <div class="description">
              <div align="center"><br></div>
              <div align="center"><strong>ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP</strong><br></div>
            </div>
            <div class="value"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col column">
          <div class="fieldContainer text ">
            <div class="description">
              <div>
                Cupim corned beef leberkas ribeye porchetta strip steak shoulder swine pork jerky meatball pork chop tail. Flank rump shankle, burgdoggen fatback porchetta pig. Hamburger cupim andouille jowl picanha brisket. Chislic bresaola pork biltong, shank boudin
                ball tip buffalo hamburger.<br><br>
                <div align="right">ABC</div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="value"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col column">
          <div class="fieldContainer text ">
            <div class="description">
              <style>
                table {
                  border: 1px solid black;
                  /* border-collapse: collapse; */
                  border-spacing: 0px;
                }
              </style>
              <table>
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td>ABCDEFghijklmnopqrstuywxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<br>
                      <div align="center"></div>
                      <ol>
                        <li>Cupim corned beef leberkas ribeye porchetta strip steak shoulder swine pork jerky meatball pork chop tail. Flank rump shankle, burgdoggen fatback porchetta pig. Hamburger cupim andouille jowl picanha brisket. Chislic bresaola pork
                          biltong, shank boudin ball tip buffalo hamburger.</li>
                        <li>Cupim corned beef leberkas ribeye porchetta strip steak shoulder swine pork jerky meatball pork chop tail. Flank rump shankle, burgdoggen fatback porchetta pig. Hamburger cupim andouille jowl picanha brisket. Chislic bresaola pork
                          biltong, shank boudin ball tip buffalo hamburger.
                        </li>
                        <li>Cupim corned beef leberkas ribeye porchetta strip steak shoulder swine pork jerky meatball pork chop tail. Flank rump shankle, burgdoggen fatback porchetta pig. Hamburger cupim andouille jowl picanha brisket. Chislic bresaola pork
                          biltong, shank boudin ball tip buffalo hamburger.
                        </li>
                        <li>Cupim corned beef leberkas ribeye porchetta strip steak shoulder swine pork jerky meatball pork chop tail. Flank rump shankle, burgdoggen fatback porchetta pig. Hamburger cupim andouille jowl picanha brisket. Chislic bresaola pork
                          biltong, shank boudin ball tip buffalo hamburger.</li>
                      </ol> <br>
                      <div align="right"></div>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table><br>
            </div>
            <div class="value"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row pageBr-B">
        <div class="col column pb-10">
          <div class="fieldContainer text ">
            <div class="description">
              <div align="center">
                <font size="5"><strong>Agrrrewrewr1</strong><br><span class="tahomaFont;"><strong>asasdsadasdsadasdasda</strong></span></font>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="value"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col column">
          <table class="tab_container pageBr-I">
            <tr>
              <td colspan="3">
                <div class="fieldContainer text ">
                  <div class="description">
                    <font size="2"></font>
                    <div align="right">年月日: 2021年10月14日<br><span style="font-size: 13px;"><span
                                                    class="tahomaFont" style="font-size: 13px;">Date: October 22,
                                                    2021</span></span>
                    </div>
                    <div align="left">John Doe<br><span class="tahomaFont">To： Mr. John Doe</span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="value"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="img_container img_container--2">
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>
                <div class="fieldContainer text ">
                  <div class="description">
                    <font size="2">asdysaoiudasoiud<br><span class="tahomaFont">adasdasdasdasdwqqwdqw</span>
                    </font>
                  </div>
                  <div class="value"></div>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <div class="fieldContainer text ">
                  <div class="description">
                    <font size="2">asdasdadas<br><span class="tahomaFont">wqeqeqe</span><br>qeqsadasd<br><span class="tahomaFont">asdasdqwdwq&nbsp;<span></span></span>
                    </font>3 months
                    <br><br>
                  </div>
                  <div class="value"></div>
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>2</td>
              <td>
                <div class="fieldContainer text ">
                  <div class="description">
                    <font size="2">Bacon ipsum dolor amet venison meatball drumstick</span><br><br>
                    </font>
                  </div>
                  <div class="value"></div>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <div class="fieldContainer text ">
                  <div class="description">
                    <font size="2">Bacon ipsum dolor amet venison meatball drumstick</span><br><br>
                    </font>
                  </div>
                  <div class="value"></div>
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>3</td>
              <td>
                <div class="fieldContainer text ">
                  <div class="description">
                    <font size="2">Bacon ipsum dolor amet venison meatball drumstick</font>
                    <br><br>
                  </div>
                  <div class="value"></div>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <div class="fieldContainer text ">
                  <div class="description">
                    <font size="2">Shank ball tip strip steak pancetta ground round kielbasa. Biltong filet mignon prosciutto, ribeye tri-tip t-bone corned beef shank short ribs jowl. Fatback ground round short loin, turducken filet mignon landjaeger capicola bresaola
                      shoulder ribeye frankfurter meatball tenderloin sausage. Swine kielbasa salami pastrami, cow flank ham alcatra. Bresaola chuck jerky doner biltong shankle shoulder corned beef rump tenderloin t-bone pork belly meatloaf pork.</font><br><br>
                  </div>
                  <div class="value"></div>
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>4</td>
              <td>
                <div class="fieldContainer text ">
                  <div class="description">
                    <font size="2"><span class="tahomaFont">Bacon ipsum dolor amet venison meatball
                                                drumstick</span></font><br><br>
                  </div>
                  <div class="value"></div>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <div class="fieldContainer text ">
                  <div class="description">
                    <font size="2"><span class="tahomaFont">Shank ball tip strip steak pancetta
                                                ground round kielbasa. Biltong filet mignon prosciutto, ribeye tri-tip
                                                t-bone corned beef shank short ribs jowl. Fatback ground round short
                                                loin, turducken filet mignon landjaeger capicola bresaola shoulder
                                                ribeye frankfurter meatball tenderloin sausage. Swine kielbasa salami
                                                pastrami, cow flank ham alcatra. Bresaola chuck jerky doner biltong
                                                shankle shoulder corned beef rump tenderloin t-bone pork belly meatloaf
                                                pork.</span>
                    </font><br><br>
                  </div>
                  <div class="value"></div>
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>5</td>
              <td>
                <div class="fieldContainer text ">
                  <div class="description">
                    <font size="2">Bacon ipsum dolor amet venison meatball drumstick</font><br>
                  </div>
                  <div class="value"></div>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <div class="fieldContainer text ">
                  <div class="description">
                    <font size="2"><span class="tahomaFont">Shank ball tip strip steak pancetta
                                                ground round kielbasa. Biltong filet mignon prosciutto, ribeye tri-tip
                                                t-bone corned beef shank short ribs jowl. Fatback ground round short
                                                loin, turducken filet mignon landjaeger capicola bresaola shoulder
                                                ribeye frankfurter meatball tenderloin sausage. Swine kielbasa salami
                                                pastrami, cow flank ham alcatra. Bresaola chuck jerky doner biltong
                                                shankle shoulder corned beef rump tenderloin t-bone pork belly meatloaf
                                                pork.</span>
                    </font><br>
                  </div>
                  <div class="value"></div>
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>6</td>
              <td>
                <div class="fieldContainer text ">
                  <div class="description">
                    <font size="2">Bacon ipsum dolor amet venison meatball drumstick</font><br>
                  </div>
                  <div class="value"></div>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <div class="fieldContainer text ">
                  <div class="description">
                    <font size="2"><span class="tahomaFont">Cupim meatloaf rump beef, filet mignon
                                                ball tip jowl kielbasa chuck. Boudin salami drumstick chislic sirloin
                                                turducken picanha brisket, chicken bresaola shank. Short loin buffalo
                                                ham, brisket kielbasa beef fatback beef ribs tail shankle tongue
                                                hamburger. Meatball t-bone sirloin, rump cupim pork loin shoulder
                                                tri-tip. Ham hock porchetta leberkas biltong jowl. Ground round fatback
                                                cow, strip steak filet mignon kielbasa brisket bresaola frankfurter
                                                porchetta. Swine corned beef turducken sirloin jerky, bresaola tongue
                                                meatball filet mignon cupim prosciutto.</span></font><br>
                  </div>
                  <div class="value"></div>
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>7</td>
              <td>
                <div class="fieldContainer text ">
                  <div class="description">
                    <font size="2"><span class="tahomaFont">Bacon ipsum dolor amet venison meatball
                                                drumstick</span></font><br>
                  </div>
                  <div class="value"></div>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <div class="fieldContainer text ">
                  <div class="description">
                    <font size="2">Cupim meatloaf rump beef, filet mignon ball tip jowl kielbasa chuck. Boudin salami drumstick chislic sirloin turducken picanha brisket, chicken bresaola shank. Short loin buffalo ham, brisket kielbasa beef fatback beef ribs tail shankle
                      tongue hamburger. Meatball t-bone sirloin, rump cupim pork loin shoulder tri-tip. Ham hock porchetta leberkas biltong jowl. Ground round fatback cow, strip steak filet mignon kielbasa brisket bresaola frankfurter porchetta. Swine
                      corned beef turducken sirloin jerky, bresaola tongue meatball filet mignon cupim prosciutto.</font><br>
                  </div>
                  <div class="value"></div>
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>8</td>
              <td>
                <div class="fieldContainer text ">
                  <div class="description">
                    <font size="2"><span class="tahomaFont">Bacon ipsum dolor amet venison meatball
                                                drumstick</span></font>
                  </div>
                  <div class="value"></div>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <div class="fieldContainer text ">
                  <div class="description">
                    Cupim meatloaf rump beef, filet mignon ball tip jowl kielbasa chuck. Boudin salami drumstick chislic sirloin turducken picanha brisket, chicken bresaola shank. Short loin buffalo ham, brisket kielbasa beef fatback beef ribs tail shankle tongue hamburger.
                    Meatball t-bone sirloin, rump cupim pork loin shoulder tri-tip. Ham hock porchetta leberkas biltong jowl. Ground round fatback cow, strip steak filet mignon kielbasa brisket bresaola frankfurter porchetta. Swine corned beef turducken
                    sirloin jerky, bresaola tongue meatball filet mignon cupim prosciutto.
                  </div>
                  <div class="value"></div>
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, please add your html (and css if neccessary) code as a (minimal and runnable) snippet so we can take a look.

Comment: @FabianS. I have added the code snippet now as an example. You can try printing in Chrome.

Comment: I don't think that is possible. CSS isn't really optimized for printing. What you could do is use `page-break-inside: avoid` on the table rows to stop the breaks in the first place: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/page-break-inside